# Make a function execute only in Kotlin interfaces?

Tags: kotlin

If I have an interface, is there any easy way I can declare a function to make it a public member, but non-overridable? Meaning, it would be exclusively callable and could not be set or overridden by its descendants

```
interface IFoo {
    fun ExecuteOnly(){
       // Do Something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read a [book](https://commonsware.com/Kotlin/) recently by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) where this situation was described.
and I quote it from there:

"... As a result, anything in an interface hierarchy is permanently open , until you start
implementing the interfaces in classes. If that is a problem — if you have some
function that you really want to mark as final — use abstract classes, not interfaces..."

Comment: Definitely what I was looking for, thank you! I figured that I would need to change my data structure, but I just wasn't sure. This solidifies my hunch

Answer (score 2):

You can define an extension function on the interface.

```
fun IFoo.executeOnly() {

}
```

It will still be possible for someone to define a member function with that name in a class implementing `IFoo` but the intention is quite clear. And anyway when using an object via a `IFoo` reference the `IFoo` extension will be chosen.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. That's not how Kotlin's `interface` is implemented.

You can use an abstract class instead

```
abstract class Foo {
    fun executeOnly(){
       // Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html

Comment: Downvotes + link to another article? My answer is still solid, you can never make a method in an interface public and non-overridable at the same time.

Answer (score -3):

Ofcourse You Can... Actually there is not much difference bw kotlin interfaces and abstract classes... simply add a body and a private modifier..

```
interface MyInterface {
    
    fun triggerTakeMe(){
        takeMe()
    }
    
   private fun takeMe(){
        println("Taken")
    }
}

class MyClass : MyInterface 

fun main() {
    
    val obj = MyClass()
    obj.triggerTakeMe()

}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. `triggerTakeMe` still can be overridden.

Comment: yes. its meant to be overridden... You tell me, what's the point of making every method private in an interface... How can we call it an interface if there it doesn't provide any interface at all... lol.

Comment: The questioner asked if there is any way to make a method in an interface public and non-overridable at the same time. This answer is not only unsatisfied but also leads to misunderstanding.